# Rails API Globalize get all translations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-api, globalize

In an API-only rails app using globalize - how do I return all the translations for a model?

ie.

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name_ar": "كرستوفر نولان",
        "name_en": "Christopher Nolan",
        "name_fr": "Christopher Nolan"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name_ar": "ميشيل جوندري",
        "name_en": "Michael Gondry",
        "name_fr": "Michael Gondry"
    },
    // ...
]
```

I've been searching for quite some time about this but I have failed to find a solution.

Comment: Doing something like this might help you: `object.translations.pluck(:locale, :title).to_h`

Comment: Could you please provide a more descriptive example? Where do I do this?

Comment: I am not sure about the data structure what you have used but I expect a `translations` association on your model, and `object.translations` should return you all the translations of that object. So doing the above will provide you a hash something like this: `{ "ar" => "ولان", "en" => "Christopher" }`, you can try this on rails console first and see if it meets your requirements and then apply it on your controller from where you return the data.

Comment: That works as you describe it. Thing is that I want to automate this procedure somehow. My models might have 5-6 translatable properties and i would like to get them as such: `[property_name]_[locale]`

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this: (not a complete efficient solution but just a try if that helps)

```
# translated attribute names
attrs = %w[title description]

def translated_attributes(objects, attributes)
  result = []
  objects.each do |obj|
    trans = {}
    obj.translations.each do |tr|
      trans['id'] = obj.id
      attributes.each do |attr|
       trans[attr + '_' + tr['locale']] = tr[attr]
     end
    end
    result << trans
  end
  result
end

translated_attributes(objects, attrs)
```

Please change the names according to your application and pass the attributes accordingly.

Comment: @Manos Are you happy with that answer? Otherwise I could probably whip something up in pure SQL (which, for obvious reasons, would be much more performant depending on the size of your result set).

Comment: No, the solution doesn't really work for me. I would appreciate a pure SQL approach

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
result = {}
Director.find_each do |director|
  result[:id] = director.id
  director.translations.each { |t| result["name_#{t[:locale]}"], result["description_#{t[:locale]}"] = t.title, t.description }
end
```

to get

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name_ar": "كرستوفر نولان",
    "name_en": "Christopher Nolan",
    "name_fr": "Christopher Nolan",
    "description_ar": "...",
    "description_en": "...",
    "description_fr": "..."
},
```